# SwiftUI: why does the keyboard "jump" when switching text field's focus?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, textfield

I have tried a simple view with two text fields. When submitting the first one, I want to give focus to the second one. Here is my code.

```
enum ContentViewFocus {
    case field1
    case field2
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var field1Text = ""
    @State private var field2Text = ""
    @FocusState private var fieldFocus: ContentViewFocus?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 24.0) {
            TextField("field 1", text: $field1Text)
                .focused($fieldFocus, equals: .field1)
                .onSubmit {
                    fieldFocus = .field2
                }
            TextField("field 2", text: $field2Text)
                .focused($fieldFocus, equals: .field2)
                .onSubmit {
                    fieldFocus = nil
                }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(24.0)
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                fieldFocus = .field1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, although this correctly gives focus to the second text field, the keyboard makes a slight "jump" animation meanwhile. What is causing this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I can explain your problem, but I am not sure it is fixable. The issue comes because the first thing `.onSubmit()` does is sets your `fieldFocus` to nil. That starts the keyboard animation which is reversed by your setting the next field as the focus. It also means your second `.onSubmit` is redundant.